# any alternative of firefox's toSource() function

Tags: javascript, json, multidimensional-array

I am using dynarch calendar and I want the selected dates ranges to be converted into strings like as firefox's `toSource()` do.

Example of converting an two-dimensional array into source:

```
[20110917, [20110920, 20110922], 20110923, [20110925, 20110926]]
```

any alternative to get this same output in other browsers too..???

I am already using jQuery 1.6.2 library.
So, I don't want any other library or bigger script to get this function to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You tagged it [json](/questions/tagged/json) already, [modern browsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Native_encoding_and_decoding_in_browsers) support the `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` methods for converting data to text (JSON representation) and text to data respectively.

In your case:

```
var arr = [20110917, [20110920, 20110922], 20110923, [20110925, 20110926]];

// yields: [20110917,[20110920,20110922],20110923,[20110925,20110926]]
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Alternative method:

```
function arr_to_string(data) {
    if (data instanceof Array) {
        var arr = [];
        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            arr.push(arr_to_string(data[i]));
        }
        return "[" + arr.join(",") + "]";
    }
    // Warning: we expect all array elements to be digits, do not use this if the
    // data can be a random string
    return data;
}
console.log(arr_to_string(arr));
```

Comment: but for other browsers like IE<9 or some older browsers which doesn't support JSON, then I have to include json.js but I want a simple solution or alternate standalone function...

Comment: What's wrong with including a compatibilty layer from http://json.org? I've added a function for converting arrays with numbers (recursively).

Comment: do you have any prototype function for this?

Comment: Arrays can contain data other than numbers.