# IE: Object doesn't support property or method 'toSource' -Ext JS

Tags: extjs

I'm decoding some JSON data in my ExtJS application. it works fine in Firefox, but in IE (Gee what a surprise) I'm getting this error:

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'toSource' 
Search.js?_dc=1393865997622, line 194 character 5
```

My Search.js:

```
var mainresponse = response.toSource(); //Works in FF
```

`response` looks like this:

```
  {
   "elements":[
      {
         "element":{
            "name":"value 1",
            "id":"element 1",
            "attributes":[
               {
                  "attrname":"id",
                  etc...
```

And my decode is:

```
  var decoded = Ext.decode( mainresponse );
                    // loop over decoded data
                    for( var i=0; i < decoded.elements.length; i++ ) {
                                    etc...
```

Is there any quick solution for this? It happens when in Browser Mode IE9.

Comment: What does Search.js look like?

Comment: I've edited to include the line from Search.js,I'm not sure what else you would need to see besides this?

Comment: `response.responseText`? By the way, post your whole code so we can know the type of `response`

Comment: Edited to include json and decode

Answer (score 2):

[`Object.prototype.toSource()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toSource) is non-standard and not supported in IE:

> Non-standard
>   This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards
>   track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not
>   work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between
>   implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @CD..., is there another method in the API I could use that would have the same effect?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378343/any-alternative-of-firefoxs-tosource-function

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem by using JSONS's `stringify` function on my `mainresponse`, rather than `response.toSource()`, before I decode it.

```
var mainresponse = JSON.stringify(response);
```